# How would I be able to access a method in a component from another component

Tags: reactjs

I have two component say **Navbar** and **Sidebar** which is rendered in App.jsx. I need a method defined inside Sidebar to be accessed in Navbar. This is the code

I have this inside Navbar.jsx

```js
export default function Navbar(props) {
  const show = props.myMethod;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is a gibberish</p>
      <p> onClick={show} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have this inside Sidebar.jsx

```js
export default function Sidebar() {
  const myMethod = () => {
    alert("Hi!!! I am Collins");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am feeling good</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now in my App.jsx I have

```js
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Navbar from "./Nabar";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />

      <Navbar myMethod={myMethod} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried to pass props to the Navbar where I need the method but it comes out with an error that myMethod is not defined.

I know this is going to be a simple thing but I just started learning react by self teaching.

Thanks in advance!!!

I tried to pass props to the Navbar where I need the method but it comes out with an error that myMethod is not defined.  I ensured the necessary things were imported in App.jsx but still the same error

Comment: Did you tried to use context ?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<myComponent propName={propValue}/>
```

The code above is calling `<myComponent/>` component and passing `propValue` as `propName` to it.
so `propValue` should exist in the component calling `<myComponent/>` so that it can be passed as props.

In your code you are trying to pass `myMethod` as `myMethod` to `<Navbar/>` from `App` but there is no `myMethod` defined there.

You can have a look at [React useContext hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext)

> React Context is a way to manage state globally.
> It can be used together with the useState Hook to share state between deeply nested components more easily than with useState alone.

or just declare `myMethod` in the App component then pass it to `SideBar` and `Navbar`

```js
function App() {
  const myMethod = () => {
    alert("Hi!!! I am Collins");;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar myMethod={myMethod} />
      <Navbar myMethod={myMethod} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Now you can access it from `Navbar` as you are already doing:

```js
const Navbar = (props) => {
 //...
<p onClick={props.myMethod}</p>
}
```

You can remove `myMethod` from `Sidebar` since `Sidebar` is now receiving the same function as `props.myMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be to hold the method declaration in `App.js` and then, pass it to it's child components (sibling) components.

Here is the code -

#### App.js

```
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import Navbar from './Navbar'

function App(){

   const myMethod = ()=>{
       alert("Hi!!! I am Collins");
   }

   return (
       <>
           <Sidebar myMethod={myMethod}/>
           <Navbar myMethod={myMethod} />
       </>
    )
}
```

#### Sidebar.js

```
export default function Sidebar({ myMethod }){
    return(
        <div>
        <p>I am feeling good</p>
    </div>
   )
}
```

#### Navbar.js

```
export default function Navbar(props){
    const show = props.myMethod;
    return(
        <div>
            <p>This is a gibberish</p>
            <p onClick={show} </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You should call Navbar component from Sidebar component.

this is NavBar.jsx

export default function Navbar(props){

    const show = props.myMethod;
    
return(
    <>
    <div>
    <p>This is a gibberish</p>
    <button onClick={show} >sideBar Button</button>
    </div>
    </>
    )
    }

this is Sidebar.jsx

import Navbar from "./Navbar";
export default function Sidebar(){

    const myMethod = ()=>{
    
    alert("Hi!!! I am Collins");
    
    }
    
    return(
    
    <div>
    
    <p>I am feeling good</p>
    <Navbar myMethod={myMethod} />
    </div>
    )
    
    }

this is app.jsx

import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'


return (
  <>
  <Sidebar />
  
  </>
  )
}


export default App;
```